# Displaying command in cmd console

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm trying to run a command in cmd using C# and am having some difficulties.  I'd like to be able to write the command to the cmd console so I can see what it's trying to run (I think there's some issue with the quotes or something, so if I could see the actual string in the command line, I'd be able to see exactly what the problem is). My code looks like this:

```
var processStartInfo  = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c"+commandString);
processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

So basically, I just want to see the string commandString written in the console. Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated.

```
string CommandLineString = @"""C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe"" ""SELECT * FROM table where date >= '2009-01-01'"" queryout  ""C:\Data\data.dat"" -S DBSW0323 -d CMS -n -T";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the problem is probably just your lack of a space after "/c".

```
var processStartInfo  = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + commandString);
```

As for viewing in a command window, instead, you will probably be better off inspecting the `Arguments` property of your `processStartInfo` instance.

**EDIT**

Taking into account the command line details you posted, I believe this is what your issue is.  Check out the following from cmd help:

> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
>   the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
>   used to process quote (") characters:
>
> 1. If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
>         on the command line are preserved:
>
>    - no /S switch
>    - exactly two quote characters
>    - no special characters between the two quote characters,
>         where special is one of: &<>()@^|
>    - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
>         the two quote characters
>    - the string between the two quote characters is the name
>         of an executable file.

Since you are using /c, you have quote and special char issues still.  Try wrapping your entire `commandString` in a set of quotes.

Take this simple example for instance (creating temp.txt manually of course):

```
string commandString = @"""C:\WINDOWS\Notepad.exe"" ""C:\temp.txt""";
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + commandString);
```

The command line to be executed will be: `/c "C:\WINDOWS\Notepad.exe" "C:\temp.txt"`, but this will fail since "C:\temp.txt" is not an executable.

If you wrap the whole thing in one last set of quotes, you should see the intended result:

```
string commandString = @"""""C:\WINDOWS\Notepad.exe"" ""C:\temp.txt""""";
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + commandString);
```

Resulting in a command line of: `/c ""C:\WINDOWS\Notepad.exe" "C:\temp.txt""` and ultimately opening notepad with your test file.

Comment: This is indeed a problem, but it's still not working unfortunately.

Comment: Can you give more information on the command and args you are using?  Could you be having an issue with the base directory the command is run from being different between your command line test and your application test?

Comment: @sooprise: If you are having trouble with escape chars, consider prefacing your strings with `@` as in `@"C:\sumptin"` instead of `"C:\\sumptin"`.

Comment: I actually am using the @ for a literal string.  I have double quotes in my string, so the double quotes are actually a pair of double quotes.

Comment: Oops, added the command to your post instead of mine.  *Fixed*

Comment: @sooprise: Answer edited taking into account your command line string addition.

Answer (score 0):

That string is not "written" to the console, it's part of the argument list for a program you launch (which in this case happens to be `cmd.exe`). Since the console created is owned by that program, unless it wants to print its arguments for its own reasons (which it won't) this is not directly doable.

If you simply want to debug then why not inspect the value of `commandString`, or write it out into a log file?

If you absolutely need the command line to be displayed in the console then you could resort to hacks (run another intermediate program that prints the command line and *then* calls `cmd.exe` with it), but unless there is some other good reason to use this approach I would not recommend it.

Comment: Jon, maybe you can give me some feedback on my approach.  When I take commandString and strip out all of the escape characters and run the command in cmd directly, it works fine, but from C#, I get the following error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.  Since the only difference between the commands are the escape characters, I feel that I might be doing something wrong here.  Not sure what the best way to fix it is.

Comment: @sooprise: First off see if you have a missing space problem.

Comment: I added my command to the original post, maybe the problem is easier to identify from there?